# Which is the neatest way to have homepage articles and a blog?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a homepage that should display a few different posts from different categories. I use the "Stick this post to the front page" option to this matter and each post permalink looks like `http://site.com/sample-post/`.

Now this site should also feature a blog with articles (these are different than the homepage ones) at `/blog` with permalinks like `http://site.com/blog/sample-post/`. I thought on doing this through custom post types. That way I'd have "Homepage articles" and "Blog Posts", but I feel like I'm overcomplicating it. Is there a way of doing it on a simpler manner?

Comment: So I created a custom post type: `milestone`. I it to be very simple: site.com lists `milestones` and site.com/blog lists regular posts. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to restrict your homepage articles from being accessible via their URL at `http://site.com/blog/`, then yes, you will need to create a separate post type for them. If, on the other hand, you don't care whether they are accessible by their own URL, but just don't want them to appear along with the "normal" blog posts, then you could easily hook into `pre_get_posts` and modify the blog query to exclude them from the default blog archive view.

Comment: So I created a custom post type: `milestone`. I it to be very simple: site.com lists `milestones` and site.com/blog lists regular posts. How do I do this?